# Combining observables that will emit differing number of values

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have 2 observables that are streaming data as a result of a database query, the amount of data each emits is variable and can be different to the other one. I'm trying to work out how I can combine them both so I can use a single subscription and push the emitted values into two different arrays, e.g.

```
let firstArray = [];
let secondArray = [];

const subscription = zip(firstObservable, secondObservable)
   .subscribe({
      next([first, second]) {
         firstArray.push(first);
         secondArray.push(second);
      },
      error(err) {
         console.log(err);
      },
      complete() {
         console.log(firstArray);
         console.log(secondArray);
      }
   });
```

The problem with this example is that using zip causes them to only capture emitted values from the shortest observable, so if `firstObservable` is emitting 2 values and `secondObservable` is emitting 10, on complete both arrays will be of length 2. I apologise if the question is ambiguous at all, I'm quite new to using observables and am struggling to entirely grasp them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use `combineLatest` but it depends on what behavior you want to achieve. Making two subscriptions should be fine as well (even now it's making internaly two subscriptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toArray` to collect all of the emitted items into an array, and `forkJoin` to wait for both observables to finish:

```js
import { of, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const o1 = of(1,2,3,4,5);
const o2 = of('a', 'b');
forkJoin([
  o1.pipe(toArray()),
  o2.pipe(toArray())
]).subscribe(console.log);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-s3enjk?file=index.ts)